# Given block matrix $M$, show determinant relationship between $M$ and the block elements of $M.$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Given that $M = \begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ C &D \end{pmatrix}$ and $M^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} P & Q \\ R & S \end{pmatrix},$ where $A, B,\dots$ are $k \times k$ matrices, show that $\det(M) \cdot \det(S) = \det(A).$

Gone through sheets of paper on this one... I feel like there is a trick and a quick answer.

Comment: From the viewpoint of the matrix $M$ (and its minor $\det A$), this is Jacobi's equality ( http://mathoverflow.net/questions/87877/jacobis-equality-between-complementary-minors-of-inverse-matrices ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write $M$ as,

$$ M =\begin{pmatrix}A&0 \\0&\text{I}  \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\text{I}&0 \\\text{C}&\text{I}  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}\text{I}&A^{-1}B \\0&D-CA^{-1}B  \end{pmatrix},$$

where $S=(D-CA^{-1}B)^{-1}$ (try the inversion, or just look it up under Schur complement).

Then the desired equality follows immediately.

Note also that this is actually the generalization of the determinant formula for $2\times 2$ matrices.

For $M=\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\c& d \end{pmatrix}_{2\times2} $,$\quad$ $\det{M}=ad-bc=a(d-ca^{-1}b).$

Comment: Small correction, $S = (D - CA^{-1}B)^{-1},$ and in the second matrix $1 = I.$  Worked out the inverse in full detail and factorizing $M$ in this way worked great for a very clear proof!

Comment: Corrected. Thank you.

Comment: Some words on why you can assume $A$ invertible would be helpful here :) (The simplest way is to replace $A$ by $A+xI$, where $x$ is a polynomial indeterminate, and where $I$ is the identity matrix of appropriate size. Then, $\det\left(A+xI\right)$ is a monic polynomial in $x$, and thus is invertible in the ring of Laurent series over the base ring; hence, the matrix $A+xI$ is invertible over that ring. At the end of the computation, you can then evaluate both sides at $x=0$ to get back the identity you wanted to prove.)